# Xlib. Получить иконку приложения

Tags: c++, x11, wxwidgets, xlib

Суть задачи в следующем: нужно получить иконку из окна приложения посредством xlib и поместить её в объект wxIcon (или wxImage или wxBitmap - не важно). Как мне удалось выяснить, есть два способа это сделать: используя свойство окна `_NET_WM_ICON` или через вызов `XGetWMHints` получить объект `XWMHints`, а из него достать `icon_pixmap`. Однако, со вторым методом проблемы возникли со старта: `icon_pixmap` определён как обычный `unsigned long` и как оттуда получить XPM-содержимое иконки я так и не нашел. Вот моя попытка реализовать первый вариант:

```
void ApplicationHelper::GetIcon(SRunningWindow* pDesc, void* pDisplay, 
TWindow iWindow, unsigned long uiIconAtom)
{
    unsigned long nitems, bytesafter;
    unsigned char *ret;
    int format;
    Atom type;
    XGetWindowProperty((Display*) pDisplay, iWindow, uiIconAtom, 0, 1, 0, AnyPropertyType, &type, &format, &nitems, &bytesafter, &ret);
    int width = *(int*)ret;
    XFree(ret);
    XGetWindowProperty((Display*) pDisplay, iWindow, uiIconAtom, 1, 1, 0, AnyPropertyType, &type, &format, &nitems, &bytesafter, &ret);
    int height = *(int*)ret;
    XFree(ret);
    int size = width * height;
    XGetWindowProperty((Display*) pDisplay, iWindow, uiIconAtom, 2, size, 0, AnyPropertyType, &type, &format, &nitems, &bytesafter, &ret);
    unsigned char* imgData = new unsigned char[width * height * 3]; // RGB data
    unsigned char* alphaData = new unsigned char[width * height]; // alpha chanel
    int offset = sizeof(long) == 8 ? 8 : 4; // for 64bit systems data represented in order: blue, green, red, alpha, followed by 4 zeros

    int imgIdx = 0;
    int alphaIdx = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < nitems; i += offset)
    {
        imgData[imgIdx] = ret[i + 2]; // R
        imgData[imgIdx + 1] = ret[i + 1]; // G
        imgData[imgIdx + 2] = ret[i]; // B
        alphaData[alphaIdx++] = ret[i + 3]; // A
        imgIdx += 3;
    }
    XFree(ret);
    wxImage img(width, height, imgData, alphaData);
    img.Rescale(16, 16);
    wxBitmap bmp(img);
    pDesc->icon.CopyFromBitmap(bmp);
}
```

С его помощью, получается выцепить какую-то картинку, но она совсем не такая, как есть у приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первые три окна должны быть иконки терминала, примерно такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но по факту получается что-то всоем не то. Вроде как, делал все в соответствии со [спецификацией](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#idm140130317554480), но в итоге ерунда какая-то.
Может кто подсказать, что не так в моей реализации или как получить XPM-содержимое иконки из `icon_pixmap`?
Спасибо.

Comment: первое, что бросается в глаза — откуда взялся отличный `offset` для amd64? второе — на LE-системе порядок байт должен быть BGRA, на BE — ARGB. значение RGBA в принципе не корректно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, по офсету, на x64 системах идет не ARGB, а ARGB, а затем 4 нуля, то есть их писать в картинку не надо, поэтому я разбираю данные по 8байт. Если предположить, что у меня LE-система, то я как раз и пытаюсь обработать порядок BGRA. Просто для wxImage нужны данные RGB формата, поэтому я это всё в RGB и перевожу.

Comment: да, с порядком байт я просмотрел, всё нормально должно быть, но вот значение `offset` меня всё же сильно смущает...сейчас гляну, что там...

Comment: А это что за платформа?

Comment: ладно, на счёт `offset`'а тоже был не прав — действительно на 64-битных системах оно пакуется в long'и (какой же всё же омерзительный этот XLib API)... [набросал](http://dpaste.com/1G2HA38) полностью аналогичный пример с Qt и всё работает, теперь я болей-менее уверен, что код в вопросе корректный... так что или проблема с wxWidget'овскими функциями, или где-то раньше: в функцию передаётся неверный `Atom`, неверный идентификатор окна или ещё сто-то в этом роде...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вдруг кто-нибудь еще столкнется с этой проблемой, то вот решение, которое сработало для меня. Идея в том, что бы из ARGB представления иконки самому собрать wxImage, ну и не стоит забывать, что _NET_WM_ICON возвращает содержимое в формате BGRA.

```
void ApplicationHelper::GetIcon(SRunningWindow* pDesc, void* pDisplay, TWindow iWindow, unsigned long uiIconAtom)
{
    unsigned long nitems, bytesafter;
    unsigned char *ret;
    int format;
    Atom type;
    XGetWindowProperty((Display*) pDisplay, iWindow, uiIconAtom, 0, 1, 0, AnyPropertyType, &type, &format, &nitems, &bytesafter, &ret);
    int width = *(int*)ret;
    XFree(ret);
    XGetWindowProperty((Display*) pDisplay, iWindow, uiIconAtom, 1, 1, 0, AnyPropertyType, &type, &format, &nitems, &bytesafter, &ret);
    int height = *(int*)ret;
    XFree(ret);
    int size = width * height;
    XGetWindowProperty((Display*) pDisplay, iWindow, uiIconAtom, 2, size, 0, AnyPropertyType, &type, &format, &nitems, &bytesafter, &ret);
    unsigned int* imgData = new unsigned int[size];
    unsigned long* ul = (unsigned long*)ret;
    for (int i=0; i < nitems; ++i)
    {
        imgData[i] = (unsigned int)ul[i];
    }
    XFree(ret);
    wxImage img(width, height);
    img.InitAlpha();
    unsigned char* argb = (unsigned char*)imgData;
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            unsigned char a = argb[3];
            unsigned char r = argb[2] * a / 255;
            unsigned char g = argb[1] * a / 255;
            unsigned char b = argb[0] * a / 255;
            img.SetRGB(x, y, r, g, b);
            img.SetAlpha(x, y, a);
            argb += 4;
        }
    }
    img.Rescale(32, 32);
    wxBitmap bmp(img);
    delete[]imgData;
    pDesc->icon.CopyFromBitmap(bmp);
}
```